# Creating a slider with the frame of a photograph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I would like to create a slider but my javascript and jQuery knowledge is not that great.

I looked at Flexslider (http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) but I am not able to customize it for the following specs:

1. no colour gaps between thumbnails
2. thumbnail timeline scrolls left to right and vice versa
3. when you click on a thumbnail it replaces the parent (larger) image.

If you could help me understand the code that I need to write, I would be very grateful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try cycle 2 plugin. You can customize it as per your need.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/caro-pager.php